# How to throw error specific exception based on response status in Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Here is my current code:

```
WebTarget resource = client.target(restEndpointURL);
Response response = resource.request().delete();
if (response.getStatusInfo() != Status.OK) {
    String message = String.format("some meaningful error message");
    throw new WebApplicationException(message, response);  
}
```

I want to throw response status specific exception from here instead of throwing generic WebApplicationException.

Comment: If the surrounding method declares that it throws WebApplicationException, you can create your own response specific exceptions that extend WebApplicationException.

Comment: I think there is no need of creating my own exception. Jersey-2 provides status code specific exceptions. I can add a switch case in my code where based on status code I'll throw the specific exception. However, I am curious whether Jersey-2 provides some utility method to achieve the same.